# mysql lookup ip address from another table with ip ranges

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as below

```
client_table
 date (timestamp)
 ip (varchar)
 value1 (int)
 value2 (int)

ip_address_table
 starting_ip (varchar)
 ending_ip (varchar)
 provider (varchar)
```

I am trying to lookup client_table entries with ip_address_table table to find the average per hour if the ip address is within the range. (if it's not within the range ignore the row)
Below is what i have come up with

```
SELECT avg(value1),avg(value2)
FROM client_table
WHERE (INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON(starting_ip) AND INET_ATON(ending_ip))
GROUP BY DATE(date),HOUR(date)
```

But, it does not give the correct output. i had a look at http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/ but struggling to write a stored function to simplify the task
any help appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: My sample data is below

```
client_table
"date"  "ip"    "value1"    "value2"
"2012-01-10 06:38:29"   "121.1.2.3" "1049"  "301"
"2012-01-11 06:41:35"   "58.1.2.3"  "16453" "794"
"2012-01-12 06:43:50"   "101.1.2.3" "1712"  "410"
"2012-01-13 06:44:04"   "121.1.10.3"    "6594"  "863"
"2012-01-14 06:45:00"   "79.1.2.3"  "879"   "614"

ip_address_table
"starting_ip" "ending_ip" "provider"
"121.0.0.0" "121.255.255.255" provider1
"79.1.2.0" "79.1.2.255" provider1
....
```

Comment: I have choose not to use this method as the performance is really poor. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see you're using the ip table, maybe try something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT avg(value1),avg(value2)
FROM client_table c, ip_address_table ip
WHERE (INET_ATON(ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON(starting_ip) AND INET_ATON(ending_ip))
GROUP BY DATE(date),HOUR(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the above query doesnt seems to be lookup the ip address correctly.for each ip in client_table row, it needs to be looked up in the ip_address_table table (check if that range is present) and give the provider info. does the above query achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, just add the provider to the selected fields. I assume here that there is a single match for each IP, otherwise you will get multiple rows for the same ip.